# how to receive data string in VB 6 from android via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, vb6

i create an application on android that listed some data. and i want to send that list data to my VB 6 via bluetooth. But i don't know how to make the coding for bluetooth connection on VB. please give me some example for this problem.
i used mscomm in vb to receive data from bluetooth but it doesn't work

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
MSComm1.CommPort = Val(Combo1.Text)
MSComm1.Settings = "38400,n,8,1"
MSComm1.PortOpen = True
MsgBox "connected !", vbInformation, "success"
Combo1.Enabled = False
Command1.Enabled = False
End Sub


Private Sub MSComm1_OnComm()
accept.Text = MSComm1.Input
End Sub
```

i used app inventor for my android program and i want to use bluetooth internal in my laptop for the receiver

Comment: Explain "doesn't work".

Comment: what do you have as port number in combo1? do you see the port in device manager?

Comment: Why are you coding in VB6? It has been dead for almost 20 years and free versions of modern VB are available.

Comment: VB 6.0 was released mid-1998, so it was dead before it was even released?  Sometimes people just want the challenge, sometimes people make money from STILL programming in it.  For what it's worth, I still program in and support applications written in PDS Basic 7.1 (DOS)

Comment: mark : my program can't receive data from my android.

Comment: @deblocker : yeah, i saw from device manager

Comment: @DaveInCaz : yeah this is for my project and my teacher challenge me to used VB 6

Comment: @BillHileman : thankyou bil :)

Comment: i'm impressed, how many people are following the VB6 tag just to post always the same comment: "VB6 is dead! Why are you coding in VB6?". VB6 is alive, here is an example, look at this Unicode suite: [Replacement of the MS common controls](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?841929-VB6-ActiveX-CommonControls-%28Replacement-of-the-MS-common-controls%29)

Comment: @deblocker I've only made that comment when it appears someone is starting new work in VB6. I think its a reasonable thing to caution new programmers about obsolete technology. Seems to be some / many cases are students so I assume the tool seleciton is not their choice. Perhaps they will rightly pressure their teachers/schools to upgrade and thereby get themselves a slightly better skillset in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have correctly configured the Port you mentioned in your question, in the `Form` where you placed your `MSComm Control`, place a `Timer` to poll the input.

Let say this Timer is called Timer1, then  inside the Timer callback add this piece of code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    If (MSComm1.InBufferCount > 0) Then
        accept.Text = MSComm1.Input
    End If
End Sub
```

Optionally, you may need also some additional defensive checks:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    MSComm1.CommPort = Val(Combo1.Text)
    MSComm1.Settings = "38400,n,8,1"
    If MSComm1.PortOpen = False Then
         MSComm1.PortOpen = True
    End If
    ' don't open a msgbox, toggle visibility of a small icon
    Combo1.Enabled = Not MSComm1.PortOpen
    Command1.Enabled = Not MSComm1.PortOpen
    Timer1.Enabled = MSComm1.PortOpen
End Sub
```

... and some clean-up code, just to show an example:

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    If MSComm1.PortOpen = True Then
        MSComm1.PortOpen = False
    End If
    Timer1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Just a last note: make sure that both devices are configured to use the exact same serial protocol, and **start trying with 9600 bps**.

Comment: thankyouu so much :') i will try this coding yaaay :D